# How to calculate the coordinates of points in a circle using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, geometry, geometry-surface

I found [this website](http://vladgotlib.com/circular/) where you try drawing a perfect circle. Just for fun I coded this small Java application, that draws a circle from the middle of your screen:

```
    // here is my massive array
    private static int[] circle = {0, -100, 1, -100, 2, -100, 3, -100, 4, -100, 5, -100, 6, -100, 7, -100, 8, -100, 9, -100, 10, -100, 11, -99, 12, -99, 13, -99, 14, -99, 15, -99, 16, -99, 17, -98, 18, -98, 19, -98, 20, -98, 21, -98, 22, -97, 23, -97, 24, -97, 25, -97, 26, -96, 27, -96, 28, -96, 29, -96, 30, -95, 31, -95, 32, -95, 33, -94, 34, -94, 35, -94, 36, -93, 37, -93, 38, -92, 39, -92, 40, -92, 41, -91, 42, -91, 43, -90, 44, -90, 45, -89, 46, -89, 47, -88, 48, -88, 49, -87, 50, -86, 51, -86, 52, -85, 53, -85, 54, -84, 55, -83, 56, -84, 57, -83, 58, -82, 59, -82, 60, -81, 61, -80, 62, -79, 63, -79, 64, -78, 65, -77, 66, -76, 67, -75, 68, -74, 69, -73, 70, -72, 71, -71, 72, -70, 73, -69, 74, -68, 75, -67, 76, -66, 77, -65, 78, -64, 79, -63, 79, -62, 80, -61, 81, -60, 82, -59, 82, -58, 83, -57, 84, -56, 83, -55, 84, -54, 85, -53, 85, -52, 86, -51, 86, -50, 87, -49, 88, -48, 88, -47, 89, -46, 89, -45, 90, -44, 90, -43, 91, -42, 91, -41, 92, -40, 92, -39, 92, -38, 93, -37, 93, -36, 94, -35, 94, -34, 94, -33, 95, -32, 95, -31, 95, -30, 96, -29, 96, -28, 96, -27, 96, -26, 97, -25, 97, -24, 97, -23, 97, -22, 98, -21, 98, -20, 98, -19, 98, -18, 98, -17, 99, -16, 99, -15, 99, -14, 99, -13, 99, -12, 99, -11, 100, -10, 100, -9, 100, -8, 100, -7, 100, -6, 100, -5, 100, -4, 100, -3, 100, -2, 100, -1, 100, 0, 100, 1, 100, 2, 100, 3, 100, 4, 100, 5, 100, 6, 100, 7, 100, 8, 100, 9, 100, 10, 100, 11, 99, 12, 99, 13, 99, 14, 99, 15, 99, 16, 99, 17, 98, 18, 98, 19, 98, 20, 98, 21, 98, 22, 97, 23, 97, 24, 97, 25, 97, 26, 96, 27, 96, 28, 96, 29, 96, 30, 95, 31, 95, 32, 95, 33, 94, 34, 94, 35, 94, 36, 93, 37, 93, 38, 92, 39, 92, 40, 92, 41, 91, 42, 91, 43, 90, 44, 90, 45, 89, 46, 89, 47, 88, 48, 88, 49, 87, 50, 86, 51, 86, 52, 85, 53, 85, 54, 84, 55, 83, 56, 84, 57, 83, 58, 82, 59, 82, 60, 81, 61, 80, 62, 79, 63, 79, 64, 78, 65, 77, 66, 76, 67, 75, 68, 74, 69, 73, 70, 72, 71, 71, 72, 70, 73, 69, 74, 68, 75, 67, 76, 66, 77, 65, 78, 64, 79, 63, 79, 62, 80, 61, 81, 60, 82, 59, 82, 58, 83, 57, 84, 56, 83, 55, 84, 54, 85, 53, 85, 52, 86, 51, 86, 50, 87, 49, 88, 48, 88, 47, 89, 46, 89, 45, 90, 44, 90, 43, 91, 42, 91, 41, 92, 40, 92, 39, 92, 38, 93, 37, 93, 36, 94, 35, 94, 34, 94, 33, 95, 32, 95, 31, 95, 30, 96, 29, 96, 28, 96, 27, 96, 26, 97, 25, 97, 24, 97, 23, 97, 22, 98, 21, 98, 20, 98, 19, 98, 18, 98, 17, 99, 16, 99, 15, 99, 14, 99, 13, 99, 12, 99, 11, 100, 10, 100, 9, 100, 8, 100, 7, 100, 6, 100, 5, 100, 4, 100, 3, 100, 2, 100, 1, 100, 0,100,-1,100,-2,100,-3,100,-4,100,-5,100,-6,100,-7,100,-8,100,-9,100,-10,100,-11,99,-12,99,-13,99,-14,99,-15,99,-16,99,-17,98,-18,98,-19,98,-20,98,-21,98,-22,97,-23,97,-24,97,-25,97,-26,96,-27,96,-28,96,-29,96,-30,95,-31,95,-32,95,-33,94,-34,94,-35,94,-36,93,-37,93,-38,92,-39,92,-40,92,-41,91,-42,91,-43,90,-44,90,-45,89,-46,89,-47,88,-48,88,-49,87,-50,86,-51,86,-52,85,-53,85,-54,84,-55,83,-56,84,-57,83,-58,82,-59,82,-60,81,-61,80,-62,79,-63,79,-64,78,-65,77,-66,76,-67,75,-68,74,-69,73,-70,72,-71,71,-72,70,-73,69,-74,68,-75,67,-76,66,-77,65,-78,64,-79,63,-79,62,-80,61,-81,60,-82,59,-82,58,-83,57,-84,56,-83,55,-84,54,-85,53,-85,52,-86,51,-86,50,-87,49,-88,48,-88,47,-89,46,-89,45,-90,44,-90,43,-91,42,-91,41,-92,40,-92,39,-92,38,-93,37,-93,36,-94,35,-94,34,-94,33,-95,32,-95,31,-95,30,-96,29,-96,28,-96,27,-96,26,-97,25,-97,24,-97,23,-97,22,-98,21,-98,20,-98,19,-98,18,-98,17,-99,16,-99,15,-99,14,-99,13,-99,12,-99,11,-100,10,-100,9,-100,8,-100,7,-100,6,-100,5,-100,4,-100,3,-100,2,-100,1,-100,0,-100,-1,-100,-2,-100,-3,-100,-4,-100,-5,-100,-6,-100,-7,-100,-8,-100,-9,-100,-10,-100,-11,-99,-12,-99,-13,-99,-14,-99,-15,-99,-16,-99,-17,-98,-18,-98,-19,-98,-20,-98,-21,-98,-22,-97,-23,-97,-24,-97,-25,-97,-26,-96,-27,-96,-28,-96,-29,-96,-30,-95,-31,-95,-32,-95,-33,-94,-34,-94,-35,-94,-36,-93,-37,-93,-38,-92,-39,-92,-40,-92,-41,-91,-42,-91,-43,-90,-44,-90,-45,-89,-46,-89,-47,-88,-48,-88,-49,-87,-50,-86,-51,-86,-52,-85,-53,-85,-54,-84,-55,-83,-56,-84,-57,-83,-58,-82,-59,-82,-60,-81,-61,-80,-62,-79,-63,-79,-64,-78,-65,-77,-66,-76,-67,-75,-68,-74,-69,-73,-70,-72,-71,-71,-72,-70,-73,-69,-74,-68,-75,-67,-76,-66,-77,-65,-78,-64,-79,-63,-79,-62,-80,-61,-81,-60,-82,-59,-82,-58,-83,-57,-84,-56,-83,-55,-84,-54,-85,-53,-85,-52,-86,-51,-86,-50,-87,-49,-88,-48,-88,-47,-89,-46,-89,-45,-90,-44,-90,-43,-91,-42,-91,-41,-92,-40,-92,-39,-92,-38,-93,-37,-93,-36,-94,-35,-94,-34,-94,-33,-95,-32,-95,-31,-95,-30,-96,-29,-96,-28,-96,-27,-96,-26,-97,-25,-97,-24,-97,-23,-97,-22,-98,-21,-98,-20,-98,-19,-98,-18,-98,-17,-99,-16,-99,-15,-99,-14,-99,-13,-99,-12,-99,-11,-100,-10,-100,-9,-100,-8,-100,-7,-100,-6,-100,-5,-100,-4,-100,-3,-100,-2,-100,-1,-100,0};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Waiting for the website to load
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        // Getting the center of the screen
        Point p = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getCenterPoint();
        // Drawing the circle by clicking on each point in the array relative to the middle of the screen
        for (int x = 0; x < circle.length; x+=2) {
            // Calculating the x and y coordinates
            int xx = p.x + circle[x];
            int yy = p.y + circle[x+1];
            click(xx, yy);
            // waiting 10ms so the website can calculate the action
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
    public static void click(int x, int y) {
        try {
            Robot bot = new Robot();
            bot.mouseMove(x, y);
            bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

The application is made to be used on this website. But my problem is as you can see, that I have to save each point of the circle in an array and that array is very big. If I wanted to expand the radius (100px) I would need to rewrite all that points. Is there a easier way of doing so? Maybe by using an equation or something like that.

Comment: You must have already come up with some formula to derive the points, no? Please tell me you didn't hand-write that entire list.

Comment: Start by looking at the pattern in your existing points. Figure out what function you can write to generate that existing list of points, then you should be able to modify it for different sized circles.

Comment: @Michael i draw a circle in paint and then looked where each pixel is relative to its center... (Yes i know, but i had nothing to do so i took my time)

Comment: @BilltheLizard i could make an equasion but it wouldnt work for bigger sizes...

Comment: Just a little hint: Some old dudes, already dead by now, have thought about lot's of stuff like: `pi` (not pie), `radiants`, `calculating circle-stuff`. Maybe that stuff can help you.

Comment: @Korashen but how do i do it? i have no clue

Comment: @Milan: You do not have to define every point in a circle. Just define the center of the circle and it's radius or diameter and then use mathematics. With radiants you can calculate each point on a circle on the fly and then do your mouse movement.

Comment: Also see here for some formulas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle

Comment: This is probably too broad - essentially it is asking how to calculate the coordinates of points in a circle prior to trying to implement that algorithm. Now that you have the circle equations, the best thing to do would be to try to implement them, and then ask a new question if you get stuck. Some new search engine searches will undoubtedly unearth ready-made sample code for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the coordinates of a point on the circumference of a circle for a given angle (in radians) by doing `{cos(angle), sin(angle)}`.

So one way we can get a list of points is to loop around and get the coordinates for every `n` degrees, where `n` is configurable (you'll need more points for a larger radius to draw a smooth circle).

I'd first declare a Point class to hold these values:

```
class Point
{
    final int x;
    final int y;

    Point(final double x, final double y)
    {
        this.x = (int) x; // we're dealing with pixels, so just truncate it
        this.y = (int) y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "{" + x + ", " + y + "}";
    }
}
```

Then we can do the following to populate an array of Points:

```
final int NUM_POINTS = 1000;
final double RADIUS = 100d;

final Point[] points = new Point[NUM_POINTS];

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; ++i)
{
    final double angle = Math.toRadians(((double) i / NUM_POINTS) * 360d);

    points[i] = new Point(
        Math.cos(angle) * RADIUS, 
        Math.sin(angle) * RADIUS
    );
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Circle Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) to draw a nearly perfect circle. You can not draw a perfect circle because of your screen resolution.

You only need x and y coordinates.

```
public Point [] generateCoordinates(Point center, int diameter) {
    //You will use algorithm here
}
```

Here is an example algorithm;

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/circle_generation_algorithm.htm

Comment: i know that you cant draw a nearly perfect circle, but how for example does paint do it?

Comment: Paint doesn't draw a perfect circle. It is using what I said above. "Circle Equations"

Comment: Yeah but How do i use this to generate an array?

Comment: this one is called bresenhams algorithm (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm for details)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/equation-of-a-circle

you should use this equation, so you can adjust circle size and precision

Comment: How do i use this to generate an array?

Comment: this method does the job (but lacks of precision, use Doubles instead if you prefer) :
 Integer[] getCirclePoints(final int centerX, final int centerY, final int radius) {
  List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int x = -radius; x != radius; x++) {
   l.add(centerX + x);
   l.add(centerY +Integer.valueOf((int) Math.sqrt(radius * radius - x * x)));
  }
  return (Integer[]) l.toArray();
 }

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to generate my array but its very slow, thats why the answer by @Michael is better...

```
int r = Integer.parseInt(rad) / 2;
    String[] circle = {"0", "0"};
    String[] circleq = {"0", "0"};
    String[] circlew = {"0", "0"};
    String[] circlee = {"0", "0"};

    for (int x = 0; x < r; x++) {
        double yy;

        yy = Math.sqrt((r*r) - (x*x));


        int y = (int) Math.round(yy);;
        circle = add(circle, Integer.parseInt("-" + x));
        circle = add(circle, Integer.parseInt("-" + y));
    }
    String[] circle2 = circle;

    for (int c = 0; c < circle2.length; c++) {
        if ((c & 1) == 0 || c == 0) {
            circleq = add(circleq, Integer.parseInt(circle2[c]));
        } else {
            circleq = add(circleq, Integer.parseInt(circle2[c].replace("-", "")));
        }
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < circle2.length; c++) {
        circlew = add(circlew, Integer.parseInt(circle2[c].replace("-", "")));
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < circle2.length; c++) {
        if ((c & 1) == 0 || c == 0) {
            circlee = add(circlee, Integer.parseInt(circle2[c].replace("-", "")));
        } else {
            circlee = add(circlee, Integer.parseInt(circle2[c]));
        }
    }
```

It saves each quarter of the circle in a seperate array.