# How to get a point at known distance in known direction

Tags: java, distance, point, direction

I have a Point in Java. I have a distance at which I want to get the new Point. I know the orientation.

How would I calculate the new Point?

If initial Point is 5, 0, 5 and I want a new point at for example 10 meters away, in the direction of my Quaternion, how do I know what point is 10 meters away?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382677/how-to-calculate-the-coordinates-of-points-in-a-circle-using-java) may answer your question (see solution)

Comment: A quaternion defines a rotation, not a direction. Do you have a reference direction that your rotation is relative to?

Comment: @Sneftel I want the new point to be created in the direction of the Y axis, forward of the point. Basically it is a player position and rotation. I need a point X meters away from the player in the direction he is facing.

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 thank you I will check this now