# Java awt draw elements around a circle

Tags: java, graphics, geometry, awt

I'm currently writing a little game and I came over a problem. I need to draw 64 small circles at the border of a big circle. So I want something like this:

[image: 64 circles arranged around a big circle]

I've already tried many things, but they didn't worked. How can this be done in java, using the java.awt.Component#paint() method and the java.awt.Graphics class?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to do any serious 2D graphics drawing in Java then the [2D Graphics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) of the Java Tutorials is a must read.

Comment: Have you tried by just drawing a hollow circle? Don't expect people to come here and give you the code. You need to show some effort and there is no code posted with your question.

Comment: If you are writing a game, I would suggest you use Java's version of openGL rather than AWT.  Or do you just want the ring of circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your basic problem comes down to "find a point on a circle based on a given angle"

A quick google will find resources like [Find the coordinates of a point on a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260096/find-the-coordinates-of-a-point-on-a-circle), now, to be frank, I'm an idiot, so I'd narrow my search to include Java, which would give us something like [How to calculate the coordinates of points in a circle using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382677/how-to-calculate-the-coordinates-of-points-in-a-circle-using-java) - sweet.

So the basic calculation might look something like

```
double xPosy = Math.cos(rads) * radius);
double yPosy = Math.sin(rads) * radius);
```

Now, this solves the core aspect of your problem.  The rest comes down to simply painting the results. See [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) as a starting point and [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) for a more detailed look into the API.

Now, taking all of the above, you might end up with a solution looking something like...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int midX = getWidth() / 2;
            int midY = getHeight() / 2;
            Dimension size = new Dimension(4, 4);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (int index = 0; index < 64; index++) {
                double angle = (360d / 64d) * index;
                Point2D poc = getPointOnCircle(angle, 100 - 4);
                Rectangle2D box = new Rectangle2D.Double(midX + poc.getX() - 2, midY + poc.getY() - 2, size.width, size.height);
                g2d.draw(box);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected Point2D getPointOnCircle(double degress, double radius) {
            double rads = Math.toRadians(degress - 90); // 0 becomes the top

            return new Point2D.Double(Math.cos(rads) * radius, Math.sin(rads) * radius);
        }
    }
}
```

So, about now, you should realise that my "squares" are, well, square, not "dimond" shaped like yours.  This is where you're going to have to start doing some work.

If I was approaching this problem I might be tempted, to create a custom shape or, apply a 45 degree transformation to the `box` and the translate it's position to render it or just rotate the whole result by 45 degrees, but this brings a whole bag of other issues depending on what you want to do with it

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it (most of this is boiler plate for setting up the containing frame and panel).  It uses the `sine and cosine` methods to compute the points of a `unit` circle.  These points are then adjusted by first multiplying by the `radius` of the desired larger circle and then centering it in the panel by adding the `center x,y` offsets.

The only really special things it contains are

1. that the outer circles are guaranteed to be spaced apart by a distance of one of their diameters.  So if the number of circles decreases the size increases.  This can be adjusted as you see fit.
2. I used `RenderingHints` to visually smooth out the curves. And finally
3. I added a simple `WheelListener` with arbitrary limits so you could see the changes when moving the mouse wheel up or down. This modifies `NCIRCLES` (something one should not do with constants) and then repaints the panel.  It is easily removed.

```
public class CircleBorder extends JPanel {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circle Border");
    static int BIG_RADIUS = 200;
    static int NCIRCLES = 60;
    static int WIDTH = 500;
    static int HEIGHT = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args ) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->new CircleBorder().start());
    }
    public void start() {
     addMouseWheelListener((we)-> {
           int rot = we.getWheelRotation();
           if (NCIRCLES < 70 && rot > 0 || NCIRCLES > 7 && rot < 0) {
               NCIRCLES += rot;
           }
              
           repaint();
       });
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.add(this);
       frame.pack();
       // center on screen
       frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
        int centerX = WIDTH/2;
        int centerY = HEIGHT/2;
        
        double angleIncrement = 2*Math.PI/NCIRCLES;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        
        // the next two lines adjusts the little radius so that each
        // outer circle will be one diameter apart.

        int bigD = (int)(Math.PI*2*BIG_RADIUS);
        int littleRadius = bigD/(NCIRCLES*4);
        
        // Compute the x and y coordinates of the center of the outer
        // circles. Then iterate once around the circle based on the
        // computed angle above to draw the circumference. The little
        // radius is subtracted to ensure those circles are
        // centered on the large circles circumference.

        double angle = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NCIRCLES; i++) {
              int x = (int)(centerX + Math.cos(angle)*BIG_RADIUS) 
                                    - littleRadius;
              int y = (int)(centerY + Math.sin(angle)*BIG_RADIUS) 
                                    - littleRadius;
              g2d.fillOval(x,y,littleRadius*2,littleRadius*2);
              angle += angleIncrement;
        }
        
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MadProgrammer for his answer. I combined his code with the suggestion to use RenderingHints by @WJS and my own ideas and the following code worked for me.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 * Thanks to <a
 * href=https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer>@MadProgrammer</a>
 * on StackOverflow for the geometry part (<a
 * href=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398744/java-awt-draw-elements-around-a-circle>Source
 * code</a>)
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JComponent {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return getParent().getSize();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            //Thanks to @WJS for the idea
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            int midX = getWidth() / 2;
            int midY = getHeight() / 2;
            int min = Math.min(getHeight() / 2, getWidth() / 2);
            Dimension size = new Dimension(min / 20, min / 20);
            double minsize = Math.min(size.getHeight(), size.getWidth());
            double radius = min - minsize;

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (int index = 0; index < 64; index++) {
                double angle = (360d / 64d) * index;
                double rads = Math.toRadians(angle - 90); // 0 becomes the top
                Point2D poc = new Point2D.Double(Math.cos(rads) * radius, Math.sin(rads) * radius);
                g2d.fillOval((int) (midX + poc.getX() - 2), (int) (midY + poc.getY() - 2), size.width, size.height);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```